# Java - Getting a varying number of json variables

Tags: java, json

I am building a tool using java, that accesses an API.

I'm trying to let the user decide, which parameters to use (via checkboxes for instance).

So the user would decide to take one of let's say 5 parameters:

```
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
```

and then I would make a call to the API using those parameters and receive a Json String as a response.

So that Json String can be either

```
{"data":[{"p1":"value1", "p2":"value2", "p3":"value3", "p4":"value4", "p5":"value5"}]}
{"data":[{"p1":"value1", "p2":"value2", "p3":"value3", "p4":"value4"}]}
{"data":[{"p1":"value1", "p2":"value2", "p3":"value3"}]}
{"data":[{"p1":"value1", "p2":"value2"}]}
or
{"data":[{"p1":"value1"}]}
```

I'm trying to print everything inside "data" to the console. This is the code I got so far:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = (JsonObject) 
parser.parse(adsInsights.toString());
System.out.println(json.get("p1").getAsString() + "\t" 
        + json.get("p2").getAsString() + "\t" 
        + json.get("p3").getAsString() + "\t" 
        + json.get("p4").getAsString() + "\t" +
        json.get("p5").getAsString()
);
```

My problem is: how do I determine which ones to print, without doing a ton of if/elses?

All I need is every variable within "data". is there a method to do this?

EDIT:

First of all, thanks for all the answers.

For future reference I guess, this is what I did:

```
//getting the keys, which the user has selected. Detailed implementation irrelevant for this matter
String selectedKeys[] = getSelectedKeys(); 

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = (JsonObject) 
parser.parse(adsInsights.toString());
for(int i = 0; i < selectedKeys.length; i++) {
    if(json.has(selectedKeys[i])) {
        System.out.print(json.get(selectedKeys[i]).getAsString() + "\t");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the Json keys no matter which keys are in it and print their values.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = (JsonObject) 
parser.parse(adsInsights.toString());

for (key: json.keys) {
            System.out.print(json.get(key).getAsString());
        }
```

Comment: there is no actual "json.keys" but i get the idea. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```java
// to check if key exists or not. if not, return empty string.
private String getValues(JSONObject jsonObj, String arg) {
        return jsonObj.get(arg) != null?(String) jsonObj.get(arg):"";
    }
```

```java
//call getValues function for every key. fetch all keys from keySet Function.
JSONObject check=(JSONObject) obj;
JSONObject data=(JSONObject) check.get("data");
Set<String> keys=data.keySet();
for(String k:keys){
            System.out.println(getValues(data,k));
}
```

Comment: went with something like this for now. turns out there already is a check method. json.has(key) returns true if the key exists within the object. so i would loop over the Strings, chosen by the user and print if json.has(key) is true

Answer (score 1):

Are you building the API as well?

I think a better data structure to return from the API would be to use an array for "data", e.g.

```
{
  "data":[ 
    { "id": "p1", "value": "value1" }, 
    { "id": "p2", "value": "value2" }, 
    { "id": "p3", "value": "value3" }, 
    { "id": "p4", "value": "value4" }, 
    { "id": "p5", "value": "value5" }
  ]
}
```

That way, the receiving code doesn't have to care about which items are in `data`, or how many. Instead it can just loop through the array and print whatever happens to be there.

Comment: im not building the api, and yeah it actually is an array. i just messed the brackets up. gonna edit it. the "print whatever happens to be there" part is what im interessted in. how exactly do i do that

Comment: using a loop, as I mentioned above. a simple `for` loop will just loop through as many elements as exist in the array at that time. If there are none, it will loop 0 times. If there are 100, it will loop 100 times.

Comment: oh hang on. i think i misread something. p1-p5 are all inside the same object

Comment: so essentially, i have a varying object, not an array of varying length

Comment: P.S. If you messed the brackets up, please correct them in the question. A lot of the other answers are predicated on the potential mis-representation of your data structure

Comment: Seen your update...ok there's an array now, but it's essentially pointless since it contains a single object which then contains all the values as keys of the object. That's just silly. You may not be building the API, but do you have a relationship with the people who are? Perhaps you can suggest that they provide the output in a more usable structure. If they really won't budge for some reason, then I guess you can go with the answer which suggests looping over all the keys in the object, but IMO it's a badly thought-out data structure, by someone who hasn't considered its usability.

Comment: its the facebook graph api. at least a part of it. there is no real way for me to cause any change there. and yeah i aggree, that the api responses are a bit silly.